# MSIX Packaging Tool "Cannot open include file"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, uwp, c++-winrt, msix

I am at a loss here and could use some help. I am using the MSIX Packaging Project in visual studio to package my c++ UWP application, however when I try to publish it I get errors:

`CL.exe /c /I"Debug\Generated Files\\" /ZI /JMC /nologo /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /sdl /Od /Oy- /D USE_IMPORT_EXPORT /D NOMINMAX /D _DEBUG /D _CONSOLE /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++20 /permissive- /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug\QMirrorCore.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc143.pdb" /external:W3 /Gd /TP /analyze- /FC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj ProviderS3.cpp`

```
Cannot open include file: 'aws/core/Aws.h': No such file or directory
Cannot open include file: 'nlohmann/json.hpp': No such file or directory
```

These includes are already set in my application project which compiles just fine in release or debug! I don't see any way to set includes in the packaging project, I thought the include directories would just be inherited from the project dependency... I should also note that before adding the json, AWS, or any other external library the packaging worked fine.

Comment: The compiler command line doesn't contain [`/I`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/i-additional-include-directories) switches for the respective libraries. That usually means one of two things: `1` You missed a platform (like `ARM` or `ARM64`) when setting up the VC++ include directories, or `2` The MSBuild task responsible for creating the MSIX package is broken. You can easily verify the former (by building for the respective platforms). The latter is harder to pinpoint, but tools like [MSBuild Log Viewer](https://msbuildlog.com/) help.

Comment: The `/D _DEBUG` command line option is odd, though. You generally wouldn't want to publish a debug build of your application.

Comment: I am packaging a debug version because it is a WinRT application and has to be installed first to work. In any case your missed platform suggestion gave me the hint I needed. It is building for x64 and x86 and I had not yet set any x86 includes. Thanks!

Comment: Local deployment for testing explains the `/D _DEBUG` flag. That makes sense. While you have discovered the issue, feel free to [submit an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Just because the problem appears trivial to you, now you know the solution, doesn't mean it wasn't valuable to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSIX Packaging default setting builds for multiple target platforms, x86 and x64. You need to make sure all includes are set for each environment on your applications project properties.